# How to use breadcrumbs_on_rails with 2 parameters in a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, breadcrumbs

I use the breadcrumbs_on_rails gem. It works with "classic" routes.

But, i got a problem with this path :

```
get '/:category_id/:id', :controller => "contents", :action => "show", :as => :category_content
```

The link generate by `add_breadcrumb @content.category.label, :category_path`  is on the category_id instead of the id (of the content object).

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

I fix my problem...

I use :     `add_breadcrumb @content.category.label, @content.category`

Comment: u did not use path at all ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://simonecarletti.com/code/breadcrumbs_on_rails/docs/#breadcrumb_element), the path passed to `add_breadcrumb`, can be a symbol, proc, or string.

Normal path helpers render out to a string, so you should be able to specify your path something like this:

```
add_breadcrumb @content.category.label, category_content_path(:category_id => @content.category.id, :id => @content.id)
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me, but i found another solution "add_breadcrumb @content.category.label, @content.category"